# PHP - check if domain matches server's IP when domain's IP is dedicated

Tags: php, dns, cross-domain, ip-address

I have a remote login script that user hosts (runs) on his server. During registration, user needs to specify a domain he will login from. When user runs script on his domain and logins to my server for the 1st time, I log his IP using:

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

When user logins 2nd time, I check if his IP address is still the same (using the same function above). Then I check if he still uses the same domain using:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Finally, besides other security checks, I also check if specified domain really points to IP address using:

```
$domain_ips_array = gethostbynamel($domain);
if (in_array($ip_address, $domain_ips_array)) {
    echo "Wonderful, domain really points to this IP";
}
```

But there's a problem when domain points to a dedicated IP. For example, if server's IP (where script is actually hosted) is 1.1.1.1 (this IP is also returned by $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), but domain is configured to use a dedicated IP 1.1.1.2, gethostbynamel function will only return 1.1.1.2, and check will fail (even if domain is actually hosted on server with IP address 1.1.1.1).

How do I solve this issue? Put simply, I need to be sure that user always runs the script on the same IP/domain, and if any of these is changed, alert is displayed.

Comment: Do you give the user the script ?

Comment: Yes, user runs script on his server. All the script files are encoded.

Comment: Now I came to an idea that I could remove the need to check if domain matches a specific IP if I was able to get location where my script is installed. Sure thing, if script is installed on userdomain.com/script/, I can get current URL in the script itself, and send it to my server. But this way it would be vulnerable because user could somehow modify the data before it's sent to my server. So if there's any way for my server to see that request comes from userdomain.com/script/ (like I can see the actual IP address) without storing it in my script and without using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a better luck with refactoring a little bit of the script you send to the user.

For example when a first login comes along, you can see the IP from the requested server.

Do your magic and return the IP to your script. Then store it somewhere and always send it after that.

This way you will always have the first IP. And then check with the `$_SERVER` variable. Domains can be changed and I think it's not that reliable.

Said it more simple, you need to have it stored somewhere.

### -EDIT

You can use the function  [gethostbyaddr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php).

This will return you the domain of the IP. So you can store the domain from the first request as well and then check it with every other.

Comment: Well, in this case I don't even need to modify the script, since I'm already storing user IPs on my server; therefore, I don't need to store the same IP in script (when user logins for Nth time, I can always compare his server's IP to IP stored in my database anyway)

Comment: Well, but I still would like to check if actual domain really points to that IP. So we go back to the original question... :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and updated solution. I already thought about this, but it causes even more problems - if domain is hosted on shared IP, gethostbyaddr will return server's hostname (not a domain), something like servername.com

Comment: I hope you find a solution to this. I will be following it with interest.